# rCharts d3pie not showing up in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am working with a d3pie rChart. It works when I view it in the rStudio viewer. When I try to enter it into a shiny app, I get an error:

**Error in addResourcePath(LIB$name, LIB$url) : object 'LIB' not found**

It wants me to tell it what library I am working with in showOutput('chart1','LIB') (e.g., Nvd3, Highcharts), but I'm not sure which one to use.

Similarly, when I save the d3pie chart as an html file, it won't open in my browser. Is there a way around this?

**Data:**

```
x <- data.frame(table = as.factor(c("A","B","C","D","E","F")), 
     value = c(518,39,337,304,56,7))
```

**Code for d3pie:**

```
require(magrittr)
require(dplyr)
require(rCharts)
rPie <- rCharts$new()
rPie$setLib("http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rChartsExtra/d3pie")
rPie$addParams(
  chartspec = list(
    header = list(
      title = list(
        text = "Breakdown of 2014 Revenue Sources"
      )
    )
    ,data = list(
      content = x
    )
  )
)
rPie
```

**server.R:**

```
require(rCharts)
require(reshape)
require(magrittr)
require(dplyr)

x <- data.frame(table = as.factor(c("A","B","C","D","E","F")), 
                value = c(518,39,337,304,56,7))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$chart1 <- renderChart2({
    rPie <- rCharts$new()
    rPie$setLib("http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rChartsExtra/d3pie")
    cat(add_lib_assets(rPie$lib,cdn=T))
    rPie$addParams(
      chartspec = list(
        header = list(
          title = list(
            text = "This is the title"
          )
        )
        , data = list(
          content = x
        )
      )
    )
    rPie$set(dom = "chart1")
    return(rPie)
  })
})
```

**ui.R:**

```
require(rCharts)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny App"),

  mainPanel(
               showOutput('chart1')
      ) 
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work in `shiny`, you need to add `d3pie` as the lib in your `showOutput`:

```
showOutput('chart1','d3pie')
```

You also to download the [extra libraries](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rChartsExtra/zipball/gh-pages) and copy/paste the d3pie folder in the same folder as where your `server.R` and `ui.R` are.

Comment: I am having trouble hunting down this d3pie folder that you mentioned. I have downloaded Ramanthv and rChart's zip file in github and it doesn't seem to be there. I have also scoured through the github repository with no luck.

Also, any thoughts on how to get the html output to work for displaying the d3pie outside of Shiny?

Comment: should be in [here](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rChartsExtra/zipball/gh-pages), you can look at this [page](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rChartsExtra/d3pie/) to display a d3pie outside of shiny

Comment: Glad I could help, if you are satisfied with the answer, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick!